# php: setting root directory for project?

Tags: php, path, root

i'm having the following url for my test project on my local server:

```
http://localhost/projects/test/
```

now i'd like to have to have the possibilty of using this as root directory for eg. includes/images - like `<img src='/img/test.jpg'>` - this way it would save me a lot of time as i could simple put it online without any path modifications/flag.

any ideas how this could work?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is not a PHP related question, but more on HTML. You may look on the [`<base>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) Tag. So instead of saying:

`<img src='/img/test.jpg'>`

go and make:

```
<head><base href="http://localhost/projects/test/" /> ... </head>
<body>
<img src="img/test.jpg" />
</body>
```

Which will in fact point to: **http://localhost/projects/test/**img/test.jpg

and for the PHP scripts use the [set_include_path()](http://www.php.net/set_include_path) function

```
<?php
  $path = '/usr/lib/pear';
  set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but any image links that *do not* begin with a forward slash `/` will be local to the document's path.

So for the document `http://localhost/projects/test/test.html`

The tag `<img src='img/test.jpg'> will point to`http://localhost/projects/test/img/test.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using relative paths and assuming that `/img/` is a subdirectory of `/test/`, no change is necessary.

If you want to use absolute paths, you can define a constant somewhere(config.php maybe) with the website root and then reference things like this:

`<?php echo "<img src = '" . $root . "/img/test.jpg'>"; ?>`

Comment: that's what i was asking :) i'd like to use the /img/ path which would always root to /projects/tests/ .. :(

Comment: As long as you are using the relative path, it doesn't matter what the root directory is. Your development machine could be http://localhost/projects/test and your production server could be http://www.yoursite.com/ and as long as `/img/` is in the same place relative to the root you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're including something you can try to use `set_include_path` and `include_path`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path